docfx markdown single entry point
I have a docfx.json which should check through selected projects and their .csproj. The output is ok with md files generated. However, I want to concatinate all of the markdown files into a single index.html as a entry for them, just like they would when I run docfx --serve. How can this be done?
This is my current docfx file:
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "outputFormat": "markdown",
      "src": [
        {
          "src": "../MyFile",
          "files": [
            "**/*.csproj"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dest": "api/MyFile"
    }
  ],
  "build": {
    "content": [
      {
        "src": ".",
        "files": [
          "index.md"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "template": [
      "default",
      "modern"
    ],
    "dest": "output"
  },
  "globalMetadata": {
    "_enableSearch": false,
    "_disableContribution": true,
    "_rootPath": "index.md"
  }
}

